# How To upload Sveltekit multiple files

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

In new svelteKit i cant upload multiple files with form multipart/form-data and multiple attribute

+page.svelte

```
<form
    action="?/add"
    method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
  >
<input
      multiple
      type="file"
      name="file"
      id="file"
      accept="image/*"
    />
```

+page.server.js

```
export const actions = {
  add: async ({ request, files }) => {
    const data = await request.formData()
  
    const file = data.get('file')

    let filename

    try {

      if (file) {

        const ext = file.name.split('.').pop()
        filename = userName + '-' +Date.now().toString() + '.' + ext
        
        let ab = await file.arrayBuffer()
        console.log(Array.from(ab));

        writeFileSync(`static/img/${filename}`, Buffer.from(ab, (e) => {
          console.log(e)
        }))
      }


      return { success: true }


    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return { success: false };

    }
  }
}
```

This code upload only one file. How can I get an array of files?

Comment: Hi @pgs, I am trying something similar. However, I get `file.arrayBuffer is not a function` with `formData = await request.formData(); const file = formData.get(`csvFile`)`. The file object does not have an array buffer method.

Comment: @sryscad `const data = await request.formData()` > `const file = data.get('file')` > `if (file instanceof Blob && file.size) {}` > `const imageData = new Uint8Array(await file.arrayBuffer())` > `await fs.promises.writeFile(`src/images/test.jpg`, imageData)` https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_buffer_blobarraybuffer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [`getAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll) function you can use if multiple values have been supplied for the same field name:

```js
const data = await request.formData();
const files = data.getAll('file');
```